# How to add dependency on a Windows Service AFTER the service is installed

Tags: windows-service, windows

I have a Windows Service that makes use of a SQL Server database.  I don't have control over the installation of the service, but would like to add a dependency on the service to ensure that it starts after SQL server has started.  (SQL server is running on the same machine as the service in question)

Is there a tool to add a dependency or possibly editing the registry directly?

Answer (score 246, accepted):

This can also be done via an elevated command prompt using the `sc` command. The syntax is:

```
sc config [service name] depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
```

**Note**: There is a space *after* the equals sign, and there is *not* one before it.

**Warning**: `depend=` parameter will **overwrite** existing dependencies list, not append. So for example, if ServiceA already depends on ServiceB and ServiceC, if you run `depend= ServiceD`, ServiceA will now depend *only* on ServiceD. (Thanks [Matt](https://serverfault.com/users/37868/matt)!)

### Examples

#### Dependency on one other service:

```
sc config ServiceA depend= ServiceB
```

Above means that ServiceA will not start until ServiceB has started. If you stop ServiceB, ServiceA will stop automatically.

#### Dependency on multiple other services:

```
sc config ServiceA depend= ServiceB/ServiceC/ServiceD/"Service Name With Spaces"
```

Above means that ServiceA will not start until ServiceB, ServiceC, and ServiceD have all started. If you stop any of ServiceB, ServiceC, or ServiceD, ServiceA will stop automatically.

#### To remove all dependencies:

```
sc config ServiceA depend= /
```

#### To list current dependencies:

```
sc qc ServiceA
```

Comment: I had originally select the answer indicating how to edit the registry. But using the SC command is more in line with what I was looking for. Thx.

Comment: If you want to see the existing dependencies before changing them with Kip's method, you can type sc qc YourServiceName

Comment: Just be careful... I just used this and didn't realize that it will overwrite existing dependencies.. there were two for my service that I don't remember.. now they're gone.. oh well! So make sure you run the command  @mivk mentioned first to see any other dependencies first.

Comment: @Matt good point, i will add a warning.

Comment: You can query currently configured dependency for a service by using `sc qc [service name]` command

Comment: Does setting up a dependency like this actually work though (with respect to SQL Server)?  I've set it up and the service is still attempting to access SQL server before it is ready -- I am not the only one, see:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556808/how-can-i-make-nservicebus-host-based-windows-service-wait-for-sql-server-to-sta

Comment: @mikey i've been using this to ensure that SQL Server starts before Tomcat for several years. I'm not sure what is going on in your case--maybe the SQL Server service tells the OS that it is "started" before it is fully initialized?

Comment: @Kip Yes that is what I've gathered, a service "start" event should return quickly -- so service developers will often fire off asynchronous threads and return success/failure right away.  In my case, the very first thing the custom service did was establish a connection to the DB.  It was trying to connect too soon, even with the dependency (and not failing, just stopping).  I was able to work around this by scheduling a batch file which waits 30 seconds and starts the service.  On newer operating systems I was able to select "Automatic [Delayed]" for the service and that works great as well.

Comment: For completeness, if you want to depend on a SQL Server instance, you have to use its name this way: MSSQL$SQL2008 (if is a SQL 2008) or MSSQL$SQL2005 (if it is SQL 2005). Do not use its "display name" ;-)

Comment: If like me, your Service has spaces in the name, enclose it in quotes.

Comment: If using powershell, make sure you use `sc.exe` otherwise you will get error:  'A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument'

Comment: I didn't need a space after the equals sign on Windows Server 2012?

Comment: Use "sc query | findstr SERVICE_NAME" to get the running services names

Answer (score 45):

You can add service dependencies by adding the "DependOnService" value to the service in the registry using the `regedit` command, services can be found under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\<Service name>`.  The details can be found at [MS KB article 193888](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888), from which the following is an excerpt from:

> To create a new dependency, select the
>   subkey representing the service you
>   want to delay, click Edit, and then
>   click Add Value. Create a new value
>   name "DependOnService" (without the
>   quotation marks) with a data type of
>   REG_MULTI_SZ, and then click OK. When
>   the Data dialog box appears, type the
>   name or names of the services that you
>   prefer to start before this service
>   with one entry for each line, and then
>   click OK.

Comment: Holy Cow!  That was the fastest answer I've ever received.  I barely got back to the home page.

Answer (score 5):

I was looking for a purely PowerShell (no regedit or sc.exe) method that can work on 2008R2/Win7 and newer, and came up with this:

Easy one is do the regedit with PowerShell:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanWorkstation' -Name DependOnService -Value @('Bowser','MRxSmb20','NSI')
```

Or, using WMI:

```
$DependsOn = @('Bowser','MRxSmb20','NSI','') #keep the empty array element at end
$svc = Get-WmiObject win32_Service -filter "Name='LanmanWorkstation'"
$svc.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$DependsOn)
```

The [Change](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901(v=vs.85).aspx) method of the Win32_Service class helped point to a solution:

```
uint32 Change(
[in] string  DisplayName,
[in] string  PathName,
[in] uint32  ServiceType,
[in] uint32  ErrorControl,
[in] string  StartMode,
[in] boolean DesktopInteract,
[in] string  StartName,
[in] string  StartPassword,
[in] string  LoadOrderGroup,
[in] string  LoadOrderGroupDependencies[],
[in] string  ServiceDependencies[]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a simple .net application to manage service dependencies, if you are interested.  It's free.

http://webpages.charter.net/bushman4/servicedependencymanager.html

Comment: It is telling me I need .NET 1.1 but I am running windows 7

Comment: .Net 1.1 needs to be installed on Windows 7.  See the answer to this question:
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/how-to-install-net-framework-11-in-windows-7-64/eb1e6232-e874-432e-ab43-17660e25e43d

Comment: Really, in 2014 you were recommending installing .NET 1.1 on Win7 instead of just recompiling it for 4.0? Thanks, no.

Answer (score 1):

In C++ (ATL) I did like this

```
bool ModifyDependOnService(void)
{
  CRegKey R;
  if (ERROR_SUCCESS == R.Open(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\services\\MyService"))
  {
    bool depIsThere = false;

    // determine if otherservice is installed, if yes, then add to dependency list.
    SC_HANDLE hSCManager = OpenSCManager(NULL, NULL, SC_MANAGER_CONNECT);
    if (hSCManager)
    {
      SC_HANDLE hService = OpenService(hSCManager, L"OtherService", SERVICE_QUERY_STATUS);
      if (hService)
      {
        depIsThere = true;
        CloseServiceHandle(hService);
      }
      CloseServiceHandle(hSCManager);
    }

    std::wstring key = L"DependOnService";
    if (depIsThere )
    {
      const wchar_t deps[] = L"RPCSS\0OtherService\0";
      R.SetValue(key.c_str(), REG_MULTI_SZ, deps, sizeof(deps));
    }

    R.Close();
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: though your appproach works, there is an official way for querying/changing a service's configuration using [QueryServiceConfigA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-queryserviceconfiga) and [ChangeServiceConfigA](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nf-winsvc-changeserviceconfiga)