# How to automatically restart RRAS service after OpenVPN

Tags: windows-server-2003, vpn, openvpn, windows

I have OpenVPN set up on a Windows Server 2003 box using a routed configuration. This allows users to connect and access the work LAN subnet.

There are remote hosts/services however that are only accessible when used via the work network. To enable access these, I push routes out to the clients to make sure traffic to these destinations goes across the VPN, and NAT the traffic using RRAS.

This all works, except: if I restart the OpenVPN service, network traffic stops working until I restart the RRAS service as well.

Is there a good way for me to make the RRAS service start/restart after OpenVPN? Are service dependencies the way to go?

Obviously I could write a batch file to do this, but I'd like to make the process as bullet-proof and obvious as I can so it doesn't cause problems for other admins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer myself, windows service dependencies are easy to establish and the best way for me to go.

See this serverfault question: [How to add dependency on a Windows Service AFTER the service is installed](https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed)

This refers to the KB article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/193888 which explains the process in detail.