# Need to setup depend services of tomcat and mysql

Tags: windows-server-2008, mysql, tomcat, service, windows-terminal-services

Trying to set service depend on each other, the command which I am using for it is as below. dependencies are not setting up. seems like there is somw thing wrong with my command : **sc config tomcat6 depend=mysql**

I got this commands from [How to add dependency on a Windows Service AFTER the service is installed](https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
sc config tomcat6 depend= mysql
```

Note the space after depend=