# Windows Service with dependency cannot start automatically

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-service, startup

I have `Service B` that is dependent on `Service A`. Both services are set for automatic(delayed) start upon boot and both services have set Recovery Action of restart in case of first, second and subsequent failures.

The scenario is:

1. Windows is booting.
2. It tries to start `Service A`.
3. `Service A` crashes upon start because it cannot initialize (e.g. connect to remote database).
4. Recovery Action kicks in and windows keep starting `Service A` at some intervals.
5. `Service A` finally starts fine (e.g. remote db is now accessible).

And that's it, Windows doesn't bother to start `Service B` despite it having Automatic (delayed) startup type. 
I'm confused a bit with this behavior. Is there anything I can do to make windows start `Service B` ?

Comment: It's possible Windows tries to start both services, but it gives up on Service B because of too many failures; what does the event log says? Services-related events (starts, stops, failures) should be present in the System log.

Comment: You say B is dependent on A. Is service A listed as a dependency in the service dependencies tab for service B?

Comment: Maybe Service A should have a startup type of Automatic (delayed).

Comment: 4 years later, I confirm Windows 10 has the same behavior.  It also happens if Service A starts successfully the first time but takes a very long while (several minutes).  Windows does not write any log entries regarding Service B.  It simply does not start it.

Answer (score 1):

Service A would not attempt to start if there was a dependency set among the two services. You need to add dependency if it is not there.

```
sc config ServiceB depend= ServiceA
```

*[How to add dependency on a Windows Service AFTER the service is installed](https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed)