# How to make a Windows Service startup dependent on Java startup?

Tags: windows, java, windows-service

I have a Windows Service running that is dependent on Java booted up. When I reboot the computer, sometimes Java will take a while to boot up. The Windows Service will attempt to start, but fail since Java has not booted up yet. Then I need to manually start the service myself.

Can I add a dependency on a Windows Service to wait for Java to boot?

Comment: It would help if you told us exactly what the service is. Also, as TomTom has said, Java is not a service. So you must mean that there is a Java application that needs to start.

Answer (score 0):

Given that Java is a runtime, not a service, your request makes exactly zero sense. Java does not start late or something, It does not start at all - not in a way that would make you dependent on waiting.

Now, there may be another service written in Java that you have to wait for - that is what service dependencies are for.

Answer (score 0):

[@Kip](https://serverfault.com/users/1687/kip) gave this solution in other post.

The link is [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/24821/how-to-add-dependency-on-a-windows-service-after-the-service-is-installed)

```
sc config [service name] depend= <Dependencies(separated by / (forward slash))>
```